# test stationarity of multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, stationarity

I am using R to make classification on multidimensional time series (MTS). I need to check the stationarity of these time series because I would like to estimate their covariance matrices. So far, I have checked the stationarity of each univariate time series in the MTS items to deduce their stationarity.

But it does not seem to be the best way to do it to me as it does not take into account the correlation terms. Does anyone knows a better way to test stationarity of MTS in R ? If not, are there some papers giving good arguments to take my approach ?

Thank you in advance,